# @font-face special characters visible in Chrome, but not FF or IE

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, fonts, font-face

I've got a WordPress site using two web fonts: [Acknowledgement](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Acknowledgement) and [Old Mill Sorts Goudy](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Sorts-Mill-Goudy). As you can see in the Font Squirrel-supplied supplied character maps, both fonts contain many of the standard special characters (especially important for this site is the E-accent-acute.

Both fonts' special characters render fine in Chrome, but only render as default fonts in FF and IE. My character encoding is set to UTF-8. I tried switching the encoding to Latin 1 and that made the special characters go missing completely.

EDIT: my font-face css calls are structured like those in this [CSS Tricks example](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so it turns out the missing special characters in the aforementioned fonts were due to the default FontSquirrel @font-face kits not being packed with all the special characters that the print version of the font comes with. You have to repack (some) Font Squirrel web fonts by uploading the print font, and then re-download your custom @font-face kit after modifying the expert settings to include certain entities.

TL;DR Missing special characters from FontSquirrel web fonts in certain browsers? Create your own custom-made font-face kits.